# Save JSON output of OpenALPR to file in user defined directory - Windows 10

Tags: windows, opencv, cmd, openalpr

I want to save the output of openalpr json format to a json or text or csv file in a user defined directory.

I tried the following, the connection is being established, the data output is appearing on command prompt, **but \output\recognitionresults.json still does not exist**

```
alpr -c eu --clock -j http://192.168.137.78:4747/mjpegfeed?640x480 \output\recognitionresults.json
```

[image]

What is there to add to the command script inorder to save the output to a file?

```
Environment: Windows 10 

OpenALPR download link: https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/releases
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try giving a full qualified path.

Comment: @ZdaR I did try, did not work. I even tried changing the "\" to "/".

Comment: I do not have a windows machine, so not eligible to comment much on this. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://doc.openalpr.com/commandline.html) you have to redirect the screen output to a file

> This command processes a list of image files provided in /source/imagefilelist.txt and writes JSON results to /out/recognitionresults.txt.
>
> $ alpr -j stdin < /source/imagefilelist.txt > /out/recognitionresults.txt

So this should do:

```
alpr -c eu --clock -j http://192.168.137.78:4747/mjpegfeed?640x480 > \output\recognitionresults.json
```